# Reflowing circular, non-BGA pads

Tags: reflow

I ordered this IC and a corresponding test PCB:

[image: diagram]

From the drawing pad lettering I was expecting a BGA device with balls, and my test PCB has pads matching the size of the pads on the IC (as recommended by the vendor). However, after a long delay I finally received the part and it is actually a flat carrier PCB with no balls:

[image: IC]

I've never seen this done before.  Can I paste the pads and reflow like a normal non-BGA part?  Since the pads are fairly small and matched to the size of the IC I suppose it should center on the pattern similar to a BGA part?  Since this is a 1 off test board I did not order a stencil and was going to apply paste using a compressed air dispenser and a needle.  How much paste should I be adding?

Comment: Would it work with zebra strips?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the part centering so much as having some pads "starved" for solder, and some with excess solder making the part sit too high off the board. The pads are fairly wide pitch (1.2 mm, not 0.5 mm) so solder bridges aren't so much a worry. If that's a hard-to-get or costly IC, it might be wise to just order a stencil. You can get laser-cut plastic stencils made for just $5 for $10.

Comment: BGA but without the balls would be called land grid array (LGA) if that helps in any way.

Comment: You can just buy solder spheres. Maybe turn it into a BGA yourself?

Comment: I think BGAs are a special case because they are so small and placed so closely together. But the pads on your component are pretty big and what's more, the pitch is enormous so it would be more like a QFN.

Answer (score 1):

Treat it like any part with bottom side pads (e.g. DFN, QFN, modern diodes/FETs):

- Put down paste with a syringe or needle
- Place part
- Heat to reflow

As the pad distance is so large, you can apply paste generously (make a small hill). It will flow in place reliably.

Answer (score 0):

With so few pads at such a large pitch it might just be worthwhile to deadbug it if this is a one off.

[image: Found on imgur]

I mean, if someone can accomplish this you can muster 32 pads, right?

(found on imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dEmX.jpg)